# Chances of survival after baiting with 1080 poison - sodium fluoroacetate

Tags: dogs, poison

Our darling dog was intentionally baited today with [sodium fluoroacetate or 1080 poison](https://kb.rspca.org.au/knowledge-base/what-should-i-do-if-suspect-my-pet-has-eaten-a-poison-bait/).

She is at the vet. She had severe seizures and a heart rate of 230. They had her sedated, she was unconscious, not sure if she would have been conscious if she was not sedated. She is intubated.

She did briefly wake up and was aware of her surroundings. She then had massive seizures, so they put her under anaethestic and intubated her again.

They found markers of the poison when they did an enema. They could not find any thing on gastric lavage, but she did have several vomits of the poisons before going to the vet.

The vet said in all his cases (seven) none of the dogs have recovered, especially since it went through her gut (the markers coming out of her bowel).

I am wondering if there's any evidence that dogs can survive this.

Elsa is a 6 year old greyhound. We believe she was likely deliberately poisoned by the same person who played a part in the death of one of our horses. So it's an extremely disturbing tale.

A picture of Elsa with her bestie Bundy. Luckily he wasn't with us on this property today.

[image]
[image]

Anyone who reads this, please send out kind thoughts or prayers for Elsa. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry for this to have happened to your dog, it's really sad.

Comment: How quickly did you get your dog to the vet and the vet start trying to help her after she was poisened?

Comment: On the wikipedia page for the poison, there is a potential therapy that was tested in monkeys.

Comment: yvette i am so sorry to hear about this,it hurts me to hear about people laying out poison intentionally to kill our pets and wildlife,there must be better ways to solve problems than this.